# Does AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction.timeRange refer to tracks range or compositions range

Tags: ios, avfoundation

So I've been wrestling with AVVideoComposition to try to get some cross-fading going on, and one thing I just wanted to clarify, does the timeRange property of my AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction refer to the timeRange of the track or the time range of the overall composition?  For example if i have a track that starts at 5 seconds in, and i want to cross-fade it in, would I give the AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction.timeRange starting at 0 or at 5 seconds?  With a 1second cross fade is it a time-range of 0-1 or 5-6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a mutable track to a video composition with:

```
composition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo,
    preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
```

There is no way to specify the time when inserting the track and I don't see a way of modifying the start time of a AVMutableCompositionTrack. So the added track is in the same time coordinate system as the mutable composition.

When you insert a segment into the track the segment takes on time coordinate system of the mutable composition track it has been added to, not the track it came from. The time is remapped.

Your track does not start at 5 seconds in. The track segment which contains content starts at 5 seconds in.

So to answer your question the time range is 5-6.

This gist using AVFoundation in OS X may help you to see what needs to be done:

https://gist.github.com/SheffieldKevin/c01789ccff2b2a87f5ea